# Two (or more) targets -> different object files, but same library

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project which is layered in one high-level code and one low-level code.  The low-level code is built like this:

```
SW_UNIT = FOO
C_OBJECTS = bar.o 
LIBRARY = lib/lib$(SW_UNIT).a
# 
.c:o:
      $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
#
.PHONY: clib    
clib: $(C_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARY)
#
$(LIBRARY): $(C_OBJECTS)
            @ar ru $(LIBRARY) $(C_OBJECTS)
```

This works OK.

I now want to have two different low-level implementations, but produce the same library which the high-level code can link with.  My attempt is quite crude:

```
SW_UNIT = FOO
C_OBJECTS = bar.o 
BAZ_C_OBJECTS = baz.o
LIBRARY = lib/lib$(SW_UNIT).a
# 
.c:o:
      $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
#
.PHONY: clib    
clib: $(BAZ_C_OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS) $(LIBRARY)
#
$(LIBRARY): $(C_OBJECTS)
            @ar ru $(LIBRARY) $(C_OBJECTS)

.PHONY: baz
baz: C_OBJECTS = $(BAZ_C_OBJECTS)
baz: clib
```

While this works and the archive only contains the respective .o-file, it looks ugly and I'd also like to only compile the corresponding .c-file, not both (or all in case of more low-level implementations).  Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: As a side note: If you are running GNU make that it contains implicit rules (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) which is why you often don't need `.c:o: ...` etc.

Comment: Suppose the library exists, and is newer than `baz.c`, and then you command `make baz`. What should Make do?

Comment: @Beta The premise here is that the configuration is set at the time of building the project - this is a reusable component.  I won't make much sense to change the invocation of 'make' after it has been called once already.  And if the user does that, it would be safe to assume that she does a 'make clean' before 'make baz'.